# Why I am getting this error "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by SidebarDesktop"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I declare a const in my SideBarDesktop component name `isSidebarSticky` which use a custom hook(`useStickyElement`) that has 2 arguments:

```
const isSidebarSticky = styleStore.contentHeight
    ? useStickyElement(sideBarDomRef, styleStore.headerHeight + styleStore.contentHeight)
    : 0;
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error: "React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by SidebarDesktop. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed." and I don't know why.

P.S. If I'm not making that verification and I just write:

```
const isSidebarSticky = useStickyElement(sideBarDomRef, styleStore.headerHeight + styleStore.contentHeight);
```

I'm not getting the error anymore.

The thing is that if I use the second example styleStore.contentHeight is not updated on time(it's 0) and I have to make that verification, otherwise the result will be `useStickyElement(sideBarDomRef, styleStore.headerHeight + 0)`. Even though `styleStore.contentHeight` will be greater then 0 eventually the `useStickyElement` will not be called anymore.

Comment: Are you asking us how to use the `useStickyElement` hook? Did you write that hook? Then you should include that code in the question. You can have conditionals inside the hook function, but the hook must be called every time your component function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React hooks can not be conditional. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Thanks. But how can I manage to call useStickyElement(sideBarDomRef, styleStore.headerHeight + styleStore.contentHeight) when  styleStore.contentHeight is !== 0  ?

Comment: Place your condition in to the hook.

Comment: I'm using this hook in other pages as well when I don't need styleStore.contentHeight and is like this: useStickyElement(sideBarDomRef, styleStore.headerHeight). I've already check that second argument not to be 0.

Comment: Place this one into a useEffect then.

Answer (score 0):

You can not enter terms in the call to hooks

If there are cases where the hooks are not called React he will not be able to compare the runs and he fails

Conditions can be inserted inside the hooks

[see here explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) in docs